# How to change weight of quote item

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, edit

I've build a module for changing the price while adding the product to the cart. This with the observer `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

Price is changing right, but I also want to change the weight for right calculation of shipping costs.

My Code:

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <zeo_framecalculator_model_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Zeo_FrameCalculator_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>updatePrice</method>
        </zeo_framecalculator_model_observer>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

---

```
public function updatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

    $item->setCustomPrice($vavatexOrder['custom-price']);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($vavatexOrder['custom-price']);

    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->setWeight(10);
}
```

Comment: I can see you are setting weight already, is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use event `sales_quote_item_set_product`. I tried your code and it worked perfectly fine then.

Comment: Forget to say taht I cahnge the weight on product view..

Comment: How are you changing the weight on product view? Its not possible until the quote is generated for the customer.

Comment: So when I try to change the weight after add to quote it should work?